# Create Hibernat Query with CriteriaBuilder including Join, Group By and Count in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my Java programm I got two entities `Invoice` and `Category` (like insurance, salary, car,...). Each `Invoice` belongs to exactly one `Category`. Now I want to display a table which lists all existing categories and the number if times they are actually used for an invoice. Like this:

[image]

The SQL would look like this:

```
select categories.name, categories.id, count(invoice.id) as usages 
  from categories 
  left join invoice on categories.id = invoice.category_id 
  group by categories.id
```

As I'm pretty new to Hibernate I studied the official documentation, but the documentation does only show examples based on a Person and Address relationship. However in my case Category does not have a direct linking to Invoice (it is the other way around: each invoice has a category id). So I played around with the code and came up with the following source code. Which obviously has one serious drawback as I do not get the categories without invoices:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CategoryWrapper> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CategoryWrapper.class);   
    Root<Invoice> invoiceRoot = criteria.from(Invoice.class);
    Join<Invoice, Category> invoiceJoin = invoiceRoot.join(Invoice_.category);

    criteria.select(
                criteriaBuilder.construct(
                        CategoryWrapper.class,
                        invoiceJoin.get(Category_.id),
                        invoiceJoin.get(Category_.name),
                        criteriaBuilder.count(invoiceRoot.get(Invoice_.id))
            )
        );
    criteria.groupBy(invoiceJoin.get(Category_.id));
    return session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

My question is: How can I get all categories with the number of usages even if no invoice exists for a specific category?

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

[... getter and setter ]

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")

public class Invoice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "amount")
private String amount;

@Column(name = "income", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
private boolean income;

[...getter and setter...]   

}
```

**EDIT1**

updated the SQL to use a left join. However using a LEFT join in the java code does not work.

```
Join<Invoice, Category> invoiceJoin = invoiceRoot.join(Invoice_.category, JoinType.LEFT);
```

I only get the categories with invoices (as shown in the image above). But in the database more categories are available:

[image: categories in database]

**EDIT2**

As invoices is the left table and categories is the right table I tried to use RIGHT join

```
Join<Invoice, Category> invoiceJoin = invoiceRoot.join(Invoice_.category, JoinType.RIGHT);
```

but that did not work

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RIGHT JOIN not
>   supported

**EDIT3**

I checked the console output: **even if I use a JoinType.LEFT (as shown in EDIT1) the programm will still use a INNER join**:

```
select category1_.id as col_0_0_, category1_.name as col_1_0_, count(invoice0_.id) as col_2_0_ from invoice invoice0_ inner join categories category1_ on invoice0_.category_id=category1_.id group by category1_.id
```

But why?

Comment: What do you mean by "OUTER JOIN is not supported in my case"? And your requirement "if no invoice exists" is also not covered with your SQL because your doing an inner join as well

Comment: As I already wrote, not getting the categories without invoices is exactly the issue with my code and I need to solve it by replacing the inner join with something else. I am asking for a solution e.g. left join with categories as the left table. But I do not know how to do it with CriteriaBuilder and Hibernate. EDIT: I also updated the question as the wording was misleading and the OUTER join hint from myself was pointless

Comment: No it's a left join. The side is the one you want. But can you show us the entities

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work with a left join. Only the categories with invoices where shown. I added the entity code in the question.

Comment: please check my last edit. I dont know why the JoinType.LEFT is ignored.